# How to get 3 chars entered with spaces in scanf into a char array?

Tags: c, scanf

I am previously a java programmer, but I'm now doing a C course at university (computer science major).

I need the user to be able to enter 3 chars,the first 2 being numbers, and the last 1 being either 'v' or 'h'.
For example "1 2 v".

I need the user to be able to enter it with the spaces in between each character.

***This is my current code:***

```
void manageInput(char box[][width]){
    char move[4];
    char input[16]; 
    while(1){

            scanf("%s", input);
            int i = 0;
            while(input[i] != 0){

                    if(input[i] != ' ' && input[i] != "\n"){
                            move[i] = input[i];
                    }
                    i++;
            }
            printf("%s\n", move);

            makeMove(box, move);
            printBox(box, height, width);
            // TODO
            if(move[0] == 'x'){
                    exit(0);
            }
    }
```

}

However if I run it, it works fine when I enter the chars with out spaces like "12v", but  If I enter "1 2 v", it will print out "1", call printBox, then print out "2", then print out box again, and so on.

If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong here, I would appreciate it.

Comment: So is is numbers or `char`/character? That should be a difference in Java, too. And limit the length of input taken by scanf, orerwise you run into _undefined behaviour_.

Comment: `char move[4] = {0};scanf(" %c %c %c", &move[0], &move[1],&move[2]);`

Comment: "enter 3 chars,the first 2 being numbers, and the last 1 being either 'v' or 'h'. For example "1 2 v"." is mis-leading.  "1 2 v" is 5 `char`, 1 more, if one counts the "enter".   Apparently code needs to read 3 non-white-space `char`.

Comment: when using scanf() (and family) with the '%s' format specifier, to avoid input buffer overruns (like the user, in this case, entering 16 or more characters), always include a max length modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer.  And always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 3):

> If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong here, I would appreciate it.

The short story is: Your code doesn't fulfill your requirements. It simply doesn't do what you want it to do.

Your requirements are:

- All fields must be one character. This requirement isn't fulfilled by your code. Your code will mistakenly accept multiple characters per field.
- There must be one space (exactly one space?) between the fields. This requirement isn't fulfilled by your code. There might be multiple spaces between the fields, and your code will mistakenly accept that.

**In fact, your code invokes undefined behaviour by accessing the `move` array out of bounds.** Consider that as a consequence of one of the above scenarios `i` might become some value higher than 3. What might happen in this code: `move[i] = input[i];`?

Your code is also way too complex. All of your functionality can be performed by `scanf` alone. It's a very powerful function, when you know how to use it correctly... I suggest reading and understanding [the manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html) multiple times, when you have an opportunity. You'll learn *a lot*!

I notice something you neglected to mention from within the logic you have presented: It's expected that the first field might also be `'x'`, which corresponds to an *exit* usecase. This is a bad design; the caller has no opportunity to clean up... but I'll run with it. You really should use `return` (and return an `int` value or something, corresponding to error/success) instead.

Let us caste that last paragraph aside, because we can simply consider `'x'` to be invalid input (and exit as a result), and I don't want to change the contracts of your functions; I'll leave that to you. The expression described so far appears to be `int x = scanf("%1[0123456789]%*1[ ]%1[0123456789]%*1[ ]%1[vh]", a, b, c);`.

Note that it is expected that `a`, `b` and `c` will have enough space to store a string of one byte in length. That is, their declaration should look like: `char a[2], b[2], c[2];`.

**Make sure you check the return value (`x`, in the example)!** If `x` is 3, it's safe to assume that the three variables `a`, `b` and `c` are safe to use. If `x` is 2, it's safe to assume that `a` and `b` are safe to use, and so on... If `x` is `EOF` or `0`, none of them are safe to use.

By checking the return value, you can reject input that doesn't match that precise pattern, that is:

- Fields that aren't exactly one byte in width will be rejected.
- Too many or too few spaces will be rejected.

Something else popped up that you have neglected to mention, and it's also present within your code: Chux mentioned that you'll likely be expecting the input to be terminated with a `'\n'` (newline) character. This can also be implemented in a number of ways using `scanf`:

- `scanf("%1*[\n]");` will attempt to read and discard precisely one `'\n'` character, but there's no way to ensure that was successful. `getchar` would be more appropriate for that purpose; something along the lines of `if (getchar() != '\n') { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }` might make sense, if you wish to ensure that the lines of input are perfectly formed and bomb out when they aren't... `#define BOMB_OUT`?
- `scanf("%*[^\n]"); scanf("%*c");` makes more sense; If you're interested in reading *one item per line*, then it makes sense to discard everything remaining on the line, and then the newline character itself. Note that your program should always tell the user when it's discarding or truncating input. You could also use `getchar` for this.

---

```
void manageInput(char box[][width]){
    for (;;) {
        char a[2], b[2], c[2];
        int x = scanf("%1[0123456789]%*1[ ]%1[0123456789]%*1[ ]%1[vh]", a, b, c);
        if (x != 3) {
            /* INVALID INPUT should cause an error value to be returned!
             * However, this function has no return value (which makes it
             * poorly designed)... Calling `exit` gives no opportunity for
             * calling code to clean up :(
             */
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (getchar() != '\n') {
#           ifdef BOMB_OUT
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
#           else
            scanf("%*[^\n]");
            getchar();
            puts("NOTE: Excess input has been discarded.");
#           endif
        }

        char move[4] = { a[0], b[0], c[0] };
        printf("%s\n", move);
        makeMove(box, move);
        printBox(box, height, width);
        // TODO
        if(move[0] == 'x'){
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Though I understand that problem, @chux, adding a space at the front would be a violation of the requirements that the OP has specified. I'll ping you in an hour or so following a modification...

Comment: @chux Thanks for your input... How does that look to you?

Answer (score 1):

`%s` reads a whitespace-delimited string with scanf, so if that's not what you want, it's not the thing to use.  `%c` reads a single character, but does not skip whitespce, so you probably also want a  (space) in your format to skip whitespace:

```
char input[3];

scanf(" %c %c %c", intput, input+1, input+2);
```

will read 3 non-whitespace characters and skip any whitespace before or between them.  You should also check the return value of `scanf` to make sure that it is 3 -- if not, there was less than 3 characters in your input before an end-of-file was reached.

Comment: This is a nice piece of information, but it needs work... It seems as though you put minimal effort in to obtain maximal score. As you later remarked, the return value of `scanf` needs to be checked; your example as it currently stands is a poor example. Furthermore, this only half-answers the question, and though it might seem like a good step in the right direction, if we interpret the OPs requirements precisely then the first field requires exactly no leading whitespace, and each of the other fields require delimiters of exactly one space character (which is not a newline or tab).

Comment: @Freenode-newbostonSebivor: The OP doesn't list any requirements, just two example inputs that should work (`12v` and `1 2 v`).  Getting a "requirement" that there be exactly one space between chars is obtuse if not simply wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's usuall a bad idea to read string via `scanf` because of potential buffer overflow. Consider using `fscanf` or better `fgets` as in

```
fgets(input, 15, stdin);
```

Note the extra byte for '\0'.

---

Also, you're comparing char to string here: `input[i] != "\n"`. It should be `input[i] != '\n'` instead.

---

And btw you can just use something like

```
int x, y;
char d;
scanf("%d%d%c", &x, &y, &d);
```

Comment: "Note the extra byte for '\0'." is not needed with `fgets()`.  Recommend `fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);`

Comment: `scanf("%d%d%c", &x, &y, &d);` will _not_ work to properly scan in OP's `"1 2 v"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is far too common to advise against using `scanf` under the basis that it is easy to misuse, even when it's the correct tool for the job. By that logic, it would make sense to advise against using C altogether. That kind of logic doesn't belong in an answer to this question.

Comment: Additionally, advising against using `scanf` under the guise that it's less safe than `fscanf` is unfounded; there's no logical explanation for that. `x` and `y` might contain *multiple digits*. If I may suggest, from one person who has learnt how to use `scanf` safely, declare `x` and `y` as `unsigned int` and use `%1u` (that's a *one*, not an *ell*); `%1d` would cause UB with regards to negative values. None of these directives enforce the "one space between fields" requirement; they might discard multiple whitespace characters (`'\n'`, `'\t'`, etc)... and **always check the return value!**

Answer (score 0):

This looks like two simple bugs.

You need to use separate indexes for move[] and input[]

```
    int i = 0;
    while(input[i] != 0){

            if(input[i] != ' ' && input[i] != "\n"){
                    move[i] = input[i];
            }
            i++;
    }
```

Imagine input of 1 2 v

input[0] != 0, so we enter the loop

it's not ' ' or '\n' either, so we copy input[0] to move[0]

so far so good

You increment i, and discover that input[1] == ' '

But then you increment i again

You discover that you are interested in input[2] (2) - so you copy it to move[2], rather than move[1]. Oops!

Then to make things worse, you never put an end-of-string character after the last valid character of move[].

Comment: also, the comparison of input[i] to "\n" is incorrect, as pointed out above. It should be '\n'